# How can a process have 970% CPU usage on a dual-core computer?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

My MacBook has a dual-core processor with hyperthreading, so 4 software cores. Seems like the maximum CPU usage would be 400%? I missed the screenshot, but today `kernel_task` shot up to 970% CPU for a split second. How is that possible?

Comment: What Macbook and cpu do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Open Activity Monitor and go to the Window menu. One option under that menu is CPU Usage. Select that and a small window comes up and shows the CPU usage for each core. I think you have 8 cores but this menu item will answer that question.

Comment: I have a dual-cpu computer and I have 8 software cores.

Comment: I have 4 cores.

Comment: interesting...  I don't know why you are seeing 800%///